# Overcome onOpen() timeout using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way I can have an onOpen() function auto refresh the page before timing out, and pick up from where it got to when the onOpen() function runs again?

Bit of background on what I am trying to achieve;

Due to the lack of print area feature on google sheets I am using a GAS script that takes a range from each sheet in the spreadsheet and copies it to a another sheet labeled 'PRINT' within the same spreadsheet. This then allows me to just print the whole 'PRINT' sheet. Each range copied over is the equivalent to an A4 page so it then prints nicely from here.

The issue I have is I create several spreadsheets every day from a template so in order to run the script that carries out this function I have to go through accepting permission for every spreadsheet.

I have overcome this somewhat by having a cell in the spreadsheet that when changed to "print" is picked up by the "onOpen()" function and knows to run the 'PRINT' function. So for example I would decide I wanted to run my 'PRINT' script but instead of accepting the permissions I just change my watched cell to "print" and refresh the page. This seems to bypass not having accepted the required permissions but sometimes it will time out before finishing the function.

```
function onOpen() {  
      var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      if(ws.getSheetByName("Title Page").getRange("F14").getValue() == "Print"){
        var title = ws.getSheetByName("Title Page")
        var calcs = title.getRange("N1").getValue() // Get number of sheets to move
        for (var i=0; i<calcs; i++) {
          var sheet = title.getRange(3+i,11).getValue(); // Get list of sheet names
          var pages = ((title.getRange(3+i,13).getValue())-(title.getRange(3+i,12).getValue()))+1 //Gets number of pages on each sheet, some have more than one. Column 12 is page from, Column 13 is page to
          var cpystart = ws.getSheetByName(sheet).getRange("G1").getValue()
          var cpy = ws.getSheetByName(sheet).getRange(1,cpystart,50,7*pages);
          var pst = ws.getSheetByName("PRINT").getLastColumn()
          cpy.copyTo(ws.getSheetByName("PRINT").getRange(1,pst+1))
          var cpyvalues = cpy.getValues();
          ws.getSheetByName("PRINT").getRange(1,pst+1,50,7*pages).setValues(cpyvalues);
        }
        ws.getSheetByName("Title Page").getRange("F14").setValue("Done")
      }

}
```

Comment: Maybe post your app script function so we can see what your doing?

Comment: Added the function code. I have a list of sheet names on the 'Title Page' sheet. The code iterates through these working out how many pages it needs to copy over from each sheet i.e., how big the range is on each sheet. 7 columns per page.

Comment: OnOpen trigger seems like a poor choice

Comment: Is there another trigger that bypasses the need to give the script permission to run?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for you but there are a lot of getValue().  You `getRange(3+i,11).getValue()` for consecutive rows so I moved it outside the loop and then access the values array.

```
function xxonOpen() {  
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var title = ws.getSheetByName("Title Page");
  if( title.getRange("F14").getValue() == "Print" ) {
    var calcs = title.getRange("N1").getValue(); // Get number of sheets to move
    var sheets = title.getRange(3,11,calcs,3).getValues(); // Get list of sheet names
    for (var i=0; i<calcs; i++) {
      //Gets number of pages on each sheet, some have more than one. Column 12 is page from, Column 13 is page to
      var pages = sheets[i][2]-sheets[i][1]+1;
      var cpySheet = ws.getSheetByName(sheets[i][0]);
      var cpystart = cpySheet.getRange("G1").getValue();
      var cpy = cpySheet.getRange(1,cpystart,50,7*pages);
      var pstSheet = ws.getSheetByName("PRINT");
      var pst = pstSheet.getLastColumn();
      cpy.copyTo(pstSheet.getRange(1,pst+1));
      var cpyvalues = cpy.getValues();
      pstSheet.getRange(1,pst+1,50,7*pages).setValues(cpyvalues);
    }
    title.getRange("F14").setValue("Done")
  }
}
```

Comment: This did seem to help somewhat in that it must run more quickly and so gets more sheets copied across before timing out. I have read that the onOpen() will run for a maximum of 30 seconds which appears to give me enough time to copy 16-19 pages(range's).

Comment: If you have to open the spreadsheet to print make the script a non-trigger script and run from the menu bar.  Script has 6 minute time limit.

Comment: Yes that is another option that I have in place but means me accepting the permissions for the script to run which is fine, but I have allot of spreadsheets. Running it onOpen() bypasses me having to allow the script to run,

Comment: It should have only asked you once for permission to run the script.  Unless you are copying it to new spreadsheet files.